# "gen" Folder not generated in Example Project

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I downloaded the Navigation Drawer Demo from here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#top

I imported the project into my eclipse but it doesn't generate a "gen" folder or the R.java file. Cleaning the project didn't help.

Comment: Did you update SDK tools recently?

Comment: It actually really was the platform-tools which hasn't updated yesterday... Thanks alot!

Comment: None of the solutions posted here worked for me: Clean, changing options, build errors, etc. The problem was caused by importing the Android project as a normal project, i.e. using:

    Import > General > Existing Projects Into Workspace

instead of using

    Import > Android > Existing Android Code Into Workspace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Update your android SDK.
2. Then go to project properties -> Android -> Select Android 4.2.2 -> OK
3. Then clean your project.
4. Add android-support-v4.jar from /libs to Build path

Comment: It actually really was the platform-tools which hasn't updated yesterday... Thanks alot!